# How to replace certain values of a multiindex?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, replace

I have a dataframe looking like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPnQ4.png) with a multiindex.
Now I want to replace all values in the cluster column equal to 1 with a 4, if the date in the row before is a Saturday.

I managed to get a boolean-array which is true for all values that need to be changed and false for all others like this:

```
a = pd.to_datetime(data_pivot.index.get_level_values(0)).dayofweek==6
b = data_pivot.index.get_level_values(1)==1

np.logical_and(a, b)
```

But now I dont know, how to change all the values in my multiindex accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not easy. A MultiIndex is made of tuples, which are immutable, and the Index itself is immutable, so we need to recreate the entire MultiIndex.

Re-create the entire MultiIndex from the arrays, where we modify the second level using `np.where` to change it to 4 when your condition is satisfied.

#### Sample data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([pd.date_range('2010-01-01', freq='d', periods=5), 
                                 [2,2,1,1,2]])
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': 1}, index=idx)
#              data
#2010-01-01 2     1
#2010-01-02 2     1
#2010-01-03 1     1
#2010-01-04 1     1
#2010-01-05 2     1
```

---

```
m = ((df.index.get_level_values(0).dayofweek == 6) 
      & (df.index.get_level_values(1) == 1))

df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.index.get_level_values(0),
                                      np.where(m, 4, df.index.get_level_values(1))])

print(df)
#              data
#2010-01-01 2     1
#2010-01-02 2     1
#2010-01-03 4     1  <- Index level 1 is changed to 4
#2010-01-04 1     1
#2010-01-05 2     1
```